# Passing a JSON Array of Objects to Controller using AJAX

Tags: jquery, .net, json, ajax, model-view-controller

I am trying to pass an array of object to controller with values posted by a form. Everytime when I pass the array, it gives me null in the Controller's action.

Below is may array of objects called Itemspecs

```
[object Array]: [Object, Object, Object]

0: Object
ItemID: 0
PropertyID: 7
Value: "hj"
ValueID: 0

1: Object
ItemID: 0
PropertyID: 8
Value: "Red"
ValueID: 0

2: Object
ItemID: 0
PropertyID: 19
Value: "jh"
ValueID: 0
```

jQuery

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     cache: false,
     url: '/Item/AddOrEdit',
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     dataType:'json',
     //data: $(form).serialize()
     data: JSON.stringify({ form, Itemspecs })
});
```

I am passing two arguments in data. The parameters `form` are the values coming from the MVC form and `Itempecs1` is my array

```
public ActionResult AddOrEdit(List<ValueViewModel> Itemspecs, ItemViewModel form)
{ 
    // Save posted data
}
```

I am receiving form values in `AddOrEdit` action, but not the array.

Array Model:

```
public class ValueViewModel
{
    public int ValueID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This Field is Required")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
}
```

This is How I am making this `itemspecs` array by combining two other arrays

```
var Value = [];
$('#SpecsPlaceHolder :input').each(function () {
    Value.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(Value + ": These Are Values");

var PropertyID = [];

$('#SpecsPlaceHolder :input').each(function (index) {
    // For debugging purposes...
    //alert(index + ': ' + $(this).attr('id'));
    PropertyID.push($(this).data("id"));
    //PropertyID.push($(this).attr('id'));

});
console.log(PropertyID + ": These Are Ids");

var Itemspecs = [];
$.each(PropertyID, function (index, value) {
    Itemspecs.push({ 'ValueID': 0, 'Value': Value[index], 'PropertyID': value, 'ItemID': 0, });
});
```

`Value = (3) ["gh", "Red", "hg"]` and `PropertyID = (3) [7, 8, 19]` then combine them to itemspecs which returns array of objects like below in console:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0:{ValueID: 0, Value: "gh", PropertyID: 7, ItemID: 0}
1:{ValueID: 0, Value: "Red", PropertyID: 8, ItemID: 0}
2:{ValueID: 0, Value: "hg", PropertyID: 19, ItemID: 0}
length:3
__proto__:Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted JSON are missing `form` date and your JSON should have `form` for `ItemViewModel form` and `Itemspecs` for `ItemViewModel form` with same naming conventions for model properties.

Your JSON should look like below

```
{
  "form": {
    "status": "0001",
    "date": "0002"
  },
  "Itemspecs": [
    {
      "ItemID": 0,
      "PropertyID": 7,
      "Value": "hj",
      "ValueID": 0
    },
    {
      "ItemID": 0,
      "PropertyID": 8,
      "Value": "Red",
      "ValueID": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Using below JS will fill missing `form` data so you can receive it in your controller

```
// sample data for test
var Itemspecs =
    [
        { "ItemID": 0, "PropertyID": 7, "Value": "hj", "ValueID": 0 },
        { "ItemID": 0, "PropertyID": 7, "Value": "hj", "ValueID": 0 }
    ]; 

var form = {};

// loop throw form and get all data
$.each($('#form1').serializeArray(), function (i, field) {
    form[field.name] = field.value || '';
});

jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    url: '/Item/AddOrEdit',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ form, Itemspecs })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I did is to Call another Ajax In the Success of the current Ajax and send form in the first one and array in the second one

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: form.action,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (response) {

                    if (response.success && response.data > 0)
                    {
                        debugger
                        var Itemspecs = [];
                    $.each(PropertyID, function (index, value) {
                        Itemspecs.push({ 'ValueID': 0, 'Value': Value[index], 'PropertyID': value, 'ItemID': response.data });
                    });

                    console.log(Itemspecs);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '@Url.Action("PostData", "Item")/',
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: JSON.stringify(Itemspecs),

                        success: function (response) {
                            if (response.success) {
                                Popup.dialog('close');
                                dataTable.ajax.reload();
                                $.notify(response.message, {
                                    globalPosition: "top center",
                                    className: "success"
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    }
                }
       });
```